# MySql implementing increase and descrase fields and get result

Tags: php, mysql

In my application i want to implementing this mySql command as a single command to use that and get result on time without use any other command by programing out of this box such as PHP or etc,

what i want to implementing action:

```
check user money 
IF user has money then
         decrease money from himself 
      AND
         increase money of other user
      RETURN result
ELSE
     RETURN result as false
```

this command is my implementation but its not correct

```
    SELECT *, (case when (money >= 200) 
     THEN
               if(
                  (update money_repositories set money = money-200 where userId = 1) 
               AND 
                  (update money_repositories set money = money+200 where userId = 34)
               ) as state
     ELSE
          false 
     END)
     as state from money_repositories where userId = 1;
```

how can i fix this command? Thank you very much

Comment: No i can not,  could you help me?

Comment: @e4c5 i can't implementing this structure, because i dont know how can i do that

Comment: Transaction is not a structure! You need to read the linked document.

Comment: @e4c5 no sir, i cant do that, because i need that to use on nodejs, transaction is not my solution, i have been forgotten  this your refer solution

Comment: but you did not mention node.js in your question and my answer covers this question perfectly.

Comment: @e4c5 yes, because i want to use this sql command on nodejs with sql libraries, for dont using async on nodejs

Comment: @e4c5 no problem, do you know nodejs?

Comment: Nopes, and I think you should post a different question outlining your use of nodejs and restate the problem there.

Answer (score 1):

What we have here is a financial transaction. It would be horrible if the money was deducted from the first user and not second user. Is it a coincidence then that mysql has something called a [transaction](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-transaction-model.html)?

You cannot have an update inside a select. You need to have two different update statements here. First to deduct from user1, second to credit into user2's account. Transactions ensure that both operations succeed together or the first query is rolled back preserving user1's money.

The other aspect of transactions ensure's that another thread does not make a similiar modification changing the balance between the two update queries.